# Complex $\Phi$ to prove the group velocity of a wavepacket

Tags: waves, wavefunction, fourier-transform, complex-numbers, dispersion

I am reading a [lecture note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/0c07cbdc9c352c39eb9539b31ded90d7_MIT8_04S16_LecNotes4.pdf) (author: Pr. Barton Zwiebach from the physics department of M.I.T., Course: 8.04 'Quantum Physics I', title:    de Broglie Wavelength and Galilean Transformations, Phase and Group Velocities, Choosing the Wavefunction for a Free Particle) and they say that in the expression $$\Psi = \int dk \Phi(k) e^{i(kx-\omega (k) t)}$$ taking $\Phi$ real or complex doesn't change the group velocity of the wavepacket.

They prove that the wavepacket moves at the velocity $$v_g = \frac{d \omega}{dk}_{|k_0}$$ for $\Phi$ real, using the *stationary phase principle* (and, in a second step, using a Taylor expansion of $\omega (k)$ around $k_0$), but not for $\Phi$ complex.

So I tried to do it on my own:

If $\Phi$ is complex then $\Phi (k) = |\Phi(k)|e^{iArg(\Phi(k))}$

Using the *stationary phase principle*, I get:

$$x-\frac{d \omega}{dk}_{|k_0}t +\frac{d (Arg(\Phi(k))}{dk}_{|k_0} =0$$

From there I don't know what to do...

Same for the Taylor expansion method, I add a complex phase to $e^{ikx}$ but then I don't know how to cancel that phase out to find the same result as for the real case.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Okay I will do it for the next posts! These are lecture notes of Pr. Barton Zwiebach from the physics department of M.I.T. 
The course is called 8.04 'Quantum Physics I'

Comment: Please also do it for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we have waves with dispersion equation $\omega
=\omega(k)$. A right-going wave-packet of finite extent,
and with initial profile $\varphi(x)$, can be
Fourier analyzed to give
$$
\varphi(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dk}{2\pi} \Phi(k)
e^{ikx}.
$$
At later times this will evolve to
$$
\varphi(x,t)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dk}{2\pi} \Phi(k) e^{ikx-i\omega(k) t}.
$$
Let us suppose that $\Phi(k)$ is non-zero only for a narrow band of
wavenumbers around $k_0$, and that, restricted to  this narrow band,  we can approximate the full
$\omega(k)$ dispersion equation  by
$$
\omega(k) \approx \omega_0+ U(k-k_0).
$$
Thus
$$
\varphi(x,t)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dk}{2\pi} \Phi(k)
e^{ik(x-Ut)-i(\omega_0-Uk_0)t}.
$$
Comparing this with the Fourier expression for the initial
profile, we find that
$$
\varphi(x,t)= e^{-i (\omega_0-Uk_0) t} \varphi(x-Ut).
$$
The pulse envelope  therefore travels at speed $U$. The individual wave crests,
on the other hand, move at the phase velocity
$\omega(k)/k$. The phase velocity  is encoded in the  $e^{-i (\omega_0-Uk_0) t}$ overall phase factor.

Comment: $φ(x,t)=e^{−i(ω_0−Uk_0)t}φ(x−Ut).$ So this holds for $ \Phi$ complex or real ? Doesn't matter if $\Phi$ is complex ?

Comment: Yes. I assume complex $\Phi$ for simplicity. If you want real $\varphi$ you must have $\Phi(-k)= [\Phi(k)]^*$ and so $\Phi$ is big near both $k_0$ and $-k_0$ and you must add the two contributions and  then the overall phase factor becomes $\cos[(\omega_0-Uk_0)t]$. Usually complex expressions are understood to have a tacit   "real part"  understood.